# I'm looking for the title of an old 'Lord of the flies' in space style book

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space

I'm trying to find the title of a book probably release in the late 90's/early 00s.

Basically this is the gist of the story:

A bunch of humans are living in a colony in space. All the kids go to school inside the colony spaceship to be taught by the ship's AI. One day, while in class, the spaceship goes into lockdown, and we learn afterwards that some aliens (native to the planet) woke up and ate pretty much everything, including all the parents.

What happens next is a lord of the flies in space kind of thing, where the kids break into a couple factions and fight each other. Eventually some survey ship full of adults come to the planet but I can't remember much else, save remarkably random details.

Anyone have any idea what this book could have been called? It's a young adult science fiction book, probably popular right around the same time as the star wars galaxy of fear books. It's probably 125-175 pages in length.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92876/looking-for-a-ya-book-about-teenagers-in-space (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

I've spent ages trying to find (possibly) the same story! I read it at school though, which means it was 80s at the latest rather than 90s or 00s...

['Earthseed', by Pamela Sargent](http://www.amazon.co.uk/books/dp/0765332159)?

> Ship hurtles through space. Deep within its core, it carries the seed of humankind. Launched by the people of a dying Earth over a century ago, its mission is to find a habitable world for the children - fifteen-year-old Zoheret and her shipmates - whom it has created from its genetic banks. To Zoheret and her shipmates, Ship has been mother, father, and loving teacher, preparing them for their biggest challenge: to survive on their own, on an uninhabited planet, without Ship's protection. Now that day is almost upon them...but are they ready to leave Ship? Ship devises a test. And suddenly, instincts that have been latent for over a hundred years take over. Zoheret watches as friends become strangers - and enemies. Can Zoheret and her companions overcome the biggest obstacle to the survival of the human race - themselves?

Comment: Earthseed takes place on a starship, not a colony, although said starship is headed for a planet, and much of the action happens in a simulation of the planet named "The Hollow". I added a description for you.